# Al usar flexbox en la creacion de una Landing Page

Tags: css, web, desarrollo

Estoy creando una Landing Page solo HTML y CSS, invocando flexbox y linkeando Bootstrap.
Aprendo que deben usarse en CSS unidades de medida que no sean pixeles ya que es una unidad absoluta. Probando y modificando veo que igual es sitio queda responsivo, aunque le coloque px al tamaño de una imagen dentro de un div. La consulta es al ya estar invocando flexbox no hace falta utilizar unidades como rem vh vw o igualmente tengo que utilizarlas para el diseño mas alla de que tenga flexbox.
Gracias.

Comment: El asunto no es así, tu utilizas las herramientas disponibles según las necesites. Si tu diseño responsivo requiere de usar px, vh o nada, dependerá del caso

Comment: Hola Yussef, gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder. Podrias ser un poco mas especifico, con algun ejemplo. Gracias.

Comment: Es algo más complejo que todo eso. Flexbox y las unidades/tamaño de texto/componente son cosas diferentes. La gente puede especificar su tamaño de fuente por defecto en el navegador (algo relativamente común entre personas con discapacidades visuales). Al usar px como unidad absoluta, el texto y los componentes se verán siempre con el mismo tamaño, cuando si hubieras usado rem/em, el tamaño se ajustaría a la configuración del navegador. Puedes probar cómo se vería tu página yendo a la configuración de Chrome (o el que uses), y en apariencia podrás cambiar el tamaño por defecto de la fuente.